# Here from the text of the file I wanted to print the details of the footballer

Tags: python

Here from the text of the file I wanted to print the details of the footballer

```py
from re import findall
f = open('soccer_player.txt', "r")
mathces = 0
textin = f.readlines()
for line in textin:
    mathces= int(('').join(findall(r'\d+', line)))
    if(mathces>50)
        print (mathces)
f.close()
```

How to do?

This is the txt file:

```
Brad Ebert,47
Brodie Smith,46
Kade Simpson,46
Luke Shuey,46
Justin Westhoff,46
Nic Naitanui,46
Chad Wingard,462
Jordan Lewis,459
Michael Johnson,459
Hamish Hartlett,458
Steven Motlop,457
Jaeger O'Meara,457
```

Comment: How does the posted code relate to your question?

Comment: Use ``` with open('soccer_player.txt") as f``` instead of opening and closing the file. Read is also the default mode, so you do not need to specify that.

Comment: what you expect the result to be and how it is different?

Comment: please add the output you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though your question is not clear, may be you want to do one of the following:

1. Printing the value (may be a score) which is greater than 50. Your code may not work due to syntax error after if statement. Correct way will be:

```
from re import findall
f = open('soccer_player.txt', "r")
mathces = 0
textin = f.readlines()
for line in textin:
    mathces= int(('').join(findall(r'\d+', line)))
    if(mathces>50):
        print (mathces)
f.close()
```

Output will be:

```
462
459
459
458
457
457
```

2. Printing the player name who has a score greater than 50. Correct way will be:

```
f = open('soccer_player.txt', "r")
mathces = 0
textin = f.readlines()
for line in textin:
    player, score = line.split(',')
    if (int(score) > 50):
        print(f"{player} ({int(score)})")
f.close()
```

Output will be:

```
Chad Wingard (462)
Jordan Lewis (459)
Michael Johnson (459)
Hamish Hartlett (458)
Steven Motlop (457)
Jaeger O'Meara (457)
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Improving upon @Debonil Ghosh, instead of using:

```py
f = open('soccer_player.txt', "r")
f.close()
```

This is a common bad practice, and python has a better solution for opening and readind files. We can use:

```
with open('soccer_player.txt') as f:
    mathces = 0
    textin = f.readlines()
    for line in textin:
        player, score = line.split(',')
    if (int(score) > 50):
        print(f"{player} ({int(score)})")
```

We can remove the `"r"` as reading is the default mode when using `with open`. We also do not need to close the file as this is automatically handled